# svn copy and edit capturing in diff and patch

Tags: svn, patch

How to capture an svn copy followed by an edit in diff to reapply it as patch in another machine?

```
svn copy a.txt b.txt
vim b.txt  <== some edits
svn diff <== this doesn't capture the copy - 
  but treats it as edit only causing problem with patch -p0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
svn diff --notice-ancestry
```

By default `svn diff` does not look at the ancestry of a file, so when you just type `svn diff` it is looking at the repository for a file name `b.txt` in the same directory.  Use the `--notice-ancestry` option to get `b.txt` to diff against `a.txt` in the repository.  Note that to actually perform the patch on the other machine you will first need to perform the same `svn copy` command, since `b.txt` won't exist.

Comment: >>>Note that to actually ... ---- yes that's exactly what I would like to avoid. notice-ancestry tip is till useful.

Comment: In that case you should be able to run the patch with the `-o` option, from the `patch` man page: -o outfile or --output=outfile  -  Send output to outfile instead of patching files in place.
`patch -o b.txt a.txt patchfile`

Comment: For one file it will work, what about for a large changelist?

Comment: @Fakrudeen - There may be a way to do that but I don't know how.  If you don't have a compelling reason not to, the best way to get those changes to the other machine would be to commit them and svn update.